# Received 3 OTP Codes at first time in Email (Amplify Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-amplify, kotlin-coroutines, aws-amplify-sdk-android

`Hi , I'm using this method to send OTP code in my email , but at first time , I received 3 different codes , In second time not problem on that , what the case ?

We have on here , View Model Class

Fragment Class

And JSON amplify Config.

```
private var awsTOTPInProgress = false

    private val getAWSLoginOTP = SingleLiveData<Resource<AuthSignInResult>>()
    val getAWSLoginOTPData: LiveData<Resource<AuthSignInResult>> get() = getAWSLoginOTP     

   viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                getAWSLoginOTP.postValue(Resource.loading(null))

                val amplify = Amplify.Auth

                val options = AWSCognitoAuthSignInOptions.builder()
                    .authFlowType(AuthFlowType.CUSTOM_AUTH_WITHOUT_SRP)
                    .build()

                amplify.signIn(username, "", options,
                    { result ->
                        Log.d("AuthQuickstart", result.toJson().toString())
                        when {
                            result.isSignedIn -> {
                                Log.d("AuthQuickstart", "Sign in succeeded")
                                getAWSLoginOTP.postValue(Resource.success(result))
                            }
                            result.nextStep.signInStep.toString() == "CONFIRM_SIGN_IN_WITH_CUSTOM_CHALLENGE" -> {
                                getAWSLoginOTP.postValue(Resource.success(result))
                            }
                            else -> {
                                getAWSLoginOTP.postValue(Resource.error("You need to make a signup, please go to the signup page.", null))
                            }
                        }

                        awsTOTPInProgress = false
                    },
                    { exception ->
                        Log.e("AuthQuickstart", "Failed to sign in", exception)
                        when {
                            exception.cause?.message.equals("Incorrect username or password.") -> {
                                getAWSLoginOTP.postValue(Resource.error("Incorrect Email Address!", null))
                            }
                            exception.message.equals("There is already a user signed in.") -> {
                                getAWSLoginOTP.postValue(Resource.error("There is already a user signed in.", null))
                            }
                        }

                        awsTOTPInProgress = false
                    }
                )
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Log.e("AuthQuickstart", "Failed to sign in", exception)
                getAWSLoginOTP.postValue(Resource.error("An error occurred during sign in.", null))
                awsTOTPInProgress = false
            }
        }
 

#On Fragment I have this 

  viewModel.awsTOTP(username)
        viewModel.getAWSLoginOTPData.observe(this, Observer {
            when (it.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    it.data.let { res ->
                        Log.e("AuthQuickStart", "Success")
                    }
                }
```

I Want to know this from Android or From Backend

Amplify Version

```
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:2.7.1'
implementation 'com.amplifyframework:core:2.8.4'
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3'
```

JSON AUTH

```
{
  "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "auth": {
    "plugins": {
      "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
        "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
        "Version": "0.1.0",
        "IdentityManager": {
          "Default": {}
        },
        "CredentialsProvider": {
          "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
              "PoolId": "-",
              "Region": "-"
            }
          }
        },
        "CognitoUserPool": {
          "Default": {
            "PoolId": "-",
            "AppClientId": "-",`your text`
            "AppClientSecret": "-",
            "Region": "-"
          }
        },
        "Auth": {
          "Default": {
            "authenticationFlowType": "CUSTOM_AUTH_WITHOUT_SRP"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```